# Routing error in vue.js - Access to XMLHttpRequest at

Tags: vue.js

i'm new in vue.js
i wrote an method for posting data and get page address (get and post) like this

> updateCategory() {
>                   this.$eventBus.$emit("loadingStatus", true);

```
            this.$axios.get("http://rimonbd.com/tutorial/api/update-category", this.clickedCategory)
                .then(res => {
                    this.$eventBus.$emit("loadingStatus", false);
                    this.showingAddModal = false;

                    if (res.data.error) {
                        this.$iziToast.error({
                            title: 'Error',
                            message: res.data.message,
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.$iziToast.success({
                            title:'Succes',
                            message:res.data.message,
                        });
```

and i got this error :'(

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://rimonbd.com/tutorial/api/get-category' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

how should i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

The website you're trying to request data doesn't allow requests from different domains. You're on localhost:8080 requesting data from and external website.

You can try

1. Use local data to test your project
2. Deploy your project under the same domain of your data.
3. Read more about CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
4. Try a hack, only for tests, don't put this in production https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

example:

```
this.$axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://rimonbd.com/tutorial/api/update-category", this.clickedCategory)
```